# Extending Contact Form 7 with IF statements

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, contact-form-7

I need to extend Contact Form 7 on a site of mine so that depending on which drop-down the user chooses, it will send the email to a different email address. I was just wondering if there was a way I could extend Contact Form 7 to do this, maybe with IF statements? (But where would I code these in if this is the best direction?)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the code that you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selectable Recipent

```
[select your-recipient "CEO|ceo@example.com"
                    "Sales|sales@example.com"
                    "Support|support@example.com"]
```

enter a corresponding mail tag [your-recipient] into the To: field in the Mail section. This ensures that the email is sent to the specific address that the sender selected.

Refer:

http://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

Comment: Hi Vasim, this is brilliant, I couldn't find this on the docs! Must of not been searching correctly. I'm wondering how I then pull the value from the drop-down to the 'To' on the 'Mail' tab?

Comment: Okay it happen some time :),It complete then mark it.Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your reply 'it happen some time'?

Comment: I mean sometime search term is small that can't cover major thing.

Comment: [_raw_your-recipient]
This field has syntax errors. How to correct this?

Comment: I've entered that into the 'To' field on the 'Mail' tab from using piping method you mentioned above, and I get an error.

Comment: I don't have anything like this.If you have please check with this,
http://www.agentwp.com/multiple-recipients-dropdown-contact-form-7

Comment: Hmm, for some reason on the Contact Form 7 docs it says you need to enter [_raw_your-recipient], but [your-recipient] seems to work fine Thanks!